# Proper way to move file to multiple locations

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I inherited some old mule flows that need to be modified and I'm wondering the proper way to handle what was previously done.

Current:

```
<processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
    <all doc:name="All">
        <file:outbound-endpoint
        path="archive"
        outputPattern="#[header:INBOUND:originalFilename]_#[function:datestamp:${standard.date.format}]_#[function:systime]"
        responseTimeout="${standard.response.timeout.millis}"
        doc:name="File Archive"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint
        path="inbound"
        outputPattern="${brand.name}.refresh.#[function:datestamp:${standard.date.format}]_#[function:systime]"
        responseTimeout="${standard.response.timeout.millis}"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        doc:name="Inbound"/>
        <logger level="WARN" message="Downloaded file to inbound/${brand.name}.refresh" doc:name="Download File Logger"/>
    </all>
</processor-chain>
```

Seeing as All is deprecated, and they say to use Scatter Gather I tried this:

```
<processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
    <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
        <file:outbound-endpoint
            path="archive"
            outputPattern="#[header:INBOUND:originalFilename]_#[function:datestamp:${standard.date.format}]_#[function:systime]"
            responseTimeout="${standard.response.timeout.millis}"
            doc:name="File Archive"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint
            path="inbound"
            outputPattern="${brand.name}.refresh.#[function:datestamp:${standard.date.format}]_#[function:systime]"
            responseTimeout="${standard.response.timeout.millis}"
            encoding="UTF-8"
            doc:name="Inbound"/>
        <logger level="WARN" message="Downloaded file to inbound/${brand.name}.refresh" doc:name="Download File Logger"/>
    </scatter-gather>
</processor-chain>
```

but this is giving me the following exception:

```
ERROR [esicustom].ClientFTPPull.stage1.02 org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
********************************************************************************
Message               : null (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException). Message payload is of type: byte[]
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-29999
Payload               : [B@11164a7b
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException)
  org.mule.VoidMuleEvent:50 (null)
2. null (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException). Message payload is of type: byte[] (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.mule.VoidMuleEvent.getMessage(VoidMuleEvent.java:50)
    at org.mule.api.routing.AggregationContext$1.evaluate(AggregationContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.select(CollectionUtils.java:517)
    at org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.select(CollectionUtils.java:498)
    at org.mule.api.routing.AggregationContext.collectEventsWithExceptions(AggregationContext.java:84)
    at org.mule.routing.CollectAllAggregationStrategy.aggregate(CollectAllAggregationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.mule.routing.ScatterGatherRouter.processResponses(ScatterGatherRouter.java:197)
    at org.mule.routing.ScatterGatherRouter.process(ScatterGatherRouter.java:135)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.processEventWithProcessor(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:308)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.routeWithProcessors(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:298)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.process(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:198)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:118)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:189)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:182)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:109)
...
********************************************************************************
```

What is the recommended way to take a file from an FTP site and dump it into two locations like this?

Comment: Hi. Could you add the entire stack trace? It will help determine which component is throwing the exception.
Also, are the modifications part of a migration to a newer version of mule? Which one are you using?

Comment: I have added the full stack trace

Comment: Sorry missed the second half of your question, this is not a migration. We are on 3.5 and at the moment I'm staying on 3.5 to hit deadlines, and then will be migrating to the latest (Presumably 3.6.1) So if there is something in 3.6.1 and not 3.5 that would be the ideal way to do it, that's fine. I'm just trying to get a forward looking vision of how I'm supposed to handle those scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for that, it made me remember I had stumbled upon a similar issue and reported it. I answered below. HTH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just came across a bug, take a look at this [issue](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7594). It is fixed in 3.6.0 and of course 3.6.1. 
Try adding a message processor after the endpoints as a workaround, as mentioned in the JIRA ticket.

Comment: So I've finally got some time to get back around to this, sorry for the late response but you're definitely correct. Moving to 3.6.1 fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Is this there in 3.7.0. I tried adding reliability to a vm transport and I am getting this.

Comment: The fix for the scatter gather should be in 3.7.0. It would be best to share your config and error to see if it's the same.

Answer (score -1):

In your definition of scatter-gather remove the processor chain scope and before itadd object-to-string transformer.

Comment: I tried this and all it does is change the error to type: String instead of type: byte[].